# SSRS Reports Viewing mode: A dire need for vertical scrolling using IE 11

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I would really like some help with this problem.

I plan on making a large set of reports, which have MANY rows. I want to keep all the rows on a single page, so I set the property "Keeptogether" for the entire tablix as true. THis works well, but I need to be able to scroll vertically to view the entire tablix (or zoom out, but this is unpractical). Currently I can only scroll horizontally. Vertical scrolling doesn't work. I don't even have a vertical scrollbar.

How can I allow vertical scrolling in report viewer in IE 11 then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to change my compatibility view settings for IE 11 (by clicking the cogwheel and selecting "Compatibility View Settings", and add the website that I was browsing the report on). This solved my problems.